# setting a fixed size in css and using it in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, size

I am new to CSS and javascript and tried to look in other messages but I cannot find an answer on my question.

I want to set all my sections sizes beforehand in css and then use these sections in javascript. But  the .width and .height attributes javascripts uses are not the hardcoded sizes in the .css file but the size that the element has at the current line where it executes the script.

portion of my html looks like this :

```
       <div id="raw">
         <p id="add">Add a new data value</p>
         <p id="remove">Remove a data value</p>

        <script src = "javascripts/dynamic_bars.js"></script>

       </div>
```

the portion of the CSS looks like this :

#raw{  position: relative; float: left; width: 100% ; min-height: 80% ;}

and in dynamic_bars.js I try to get the width of the raw ID element :

var h = document.getElementById('raw').scrollHeight;

console.log(h);

var w = ($(this).width() * 0.8);
  var h = ($(this).height() / 3) ;

scrollHeight is only the height of my add and remove text (

elements)

The $this.height works but that is the height of the whole screen not of my raw element.

If I use the DOM inspector I can see that the height of my raw section is indeed 80% of its parent.
But when the javascript was running (which creates svg elements in the raw section) it only had the size  of the previous added

elements.

Is there a way to get to the min-height attribute of CSS in javascript ??

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.css()` to return any property value. For example

`$(this).css('min-height')`

would return value of min-height property

Comment: This works indeed for pixels (px) but it does not seems to work for %. In the beginning the height % was not working at all until I set for all the raw id parents also the height property. When I used pixels as height this was not needed. I think CSS does not known the real size yet when using % until the whole page is rendered (!?)

Answer (score 0):

User the .css() feature.

For example:

```
$("#raw").css("height");
```

In this case if you set the height property to 100 px in the css, javascript will also get the 100 px.

Comment: This works indeed for pixels (px) but it does not seems to work for %.